# iOS app running through a web page

Tags: ios, web

Is there a way to make an iOS app written in Objective-C run from a web page?

Like a demo of the app.

I don't want to rewrite using PhoneGap or HTML5.

Comment: reframe your question, and tell us exactly what is the problem?

Comment: what you probably want is an emulator that runs in a web page - however, I'm not aware of such a product in existence.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.

You are misunderstanding the type of applications that you make. In ios you are making machine encoded applications -- applications that run in arm processors, on specific touchscreens with specific memory and storage and hardware (accelerometer etc). On the webserver you are running scripts that are being interpreted from an interpreter such as php, ruby, python, etc.

So the only way to do this is via video. Capture the usage of your app in the simulator and show it on your website as a flash file.

Comment: I'd actually recommend an H.264 encoded video over flash in the HTML5 video tag due to the lack of flash support on iOS devices.

Comment: Yes, but I assume that he wants a showcase for the app to be seen from webpages. Nevertheless +1.

Answer (score 0):

[pieceable.com](http://pieceable.com)'s viewer allows you to run an iOS app inside a web browser